# Getting 502 error at specific time (i.e 10 PM) once in 24 hours

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, http-status-code-502

I have deployed a .Net Core (MVC) Application on IIS server which is throwing 502 error exactly at 10 PM on daily basis, otherwise the application works fine the whole time. I have reviewed my code several time and removed every extra things from the code, but still getting this error at that specific time. Please help.[image]

Comment: Have you set up the application pool to recycle at a specific time?

Comment: @samwu, yes I have just set the time i.e 120 min. So, it'll recycle after every 120 min.

Comment: Can you show me your web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through server logs to understand what is going on at 10 PM? To find logs, search for the Event Viewer. Alternatively, from the Control Panel, choose Administrative Tools and then Event Viewer.
System: Expand Windows Logs; System will be listed underneath.
Filter the log for networking entries
Diagnostics-Networking: Expand Applications and Services Logs, then Microsoft, then Windows.

Comment: I did check it, and there is no error. There is just warning like 
"A process serving application pool 'domainname' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '1564'." 
and this warning do not come at that specific time. Even nothing happened at that specific time. I'm extremely worried that why the site is throwing 502 error only for some time at 10 PM. After a few seconds (round about 30-35 sec) it starts working fine.